# Elasticsearch distinct filter values

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, distinct, nosql

I have a large document store in elasticsearch and would like to retrieve the distinct filter values for display on HTML drop-downs.

An example would be something like

```
[
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "deparments": [
            {
                "name": "Accounts"
            },
            {
                "name": "Management"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Jane Smith",
        "deparments": [
            {
                "name": "IT"
            },
            {
                "name": "Management"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The drop-down should have a list of departments, i.e. IT, Account and Management.

Would some kind person please point me in the right direction for retrieving a distinct list of departments from elasticsearch?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a job for a `terms` aggregation ([documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation)).

You can have the distinct `departments` values like this :

```
POST company/employee/_search
{
  "size":0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_departments": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "departments.name",
        "size": 0 //see note 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which, in your example, outputs :

```
{
   ...
   "aggregations": {
      "by_departments": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "management", //see note 2
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "accounts",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "it",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Two additional notes :

- setting `size` to 0 will set the maximum buckets number to Integer.MAX_VALUE. Don't use it if there are too many `departments` distinct values.
- you can see that the keys are `terms` resulting of analyzing `departments` values. Be sure to use your `terms` aggregation on a field mapped as `not_analyzed` .

For example, with our default mapping (`departments.name` is an `analyzed` string), adding this employee:

```
{
  "name": "Bill Gates",
  "departments": [
    {
      "name": "IT"
    },
    {
      "name": "Human Resource"
    }
  ]
}
```

will cause this kind of result:

```
{
   ...
   "aggregations": {
      "by_departments": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "it",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "management",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "accounts",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "human",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "resource",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

With a correct mapping :

```
POST company
{
  "mappings": {
    "employee": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "departments": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The same request ends up outputting :

```
{
   ...
   "aggregations": {
      "by_departments": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "IT",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "Management",
               "doc_count": 2
            },
            {
               "key": "Accounts",
               "doc_count": 1
            },
            {
               "key": "Human Resource",
               "doc_count": 1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!